# Show that the function $f(x) = x^5 - 10x^3 + 50x - 21$ is an increasing function for all x values.

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, inequality

I have worked out that $dy/dx = 5x^4 - 30x^2 + 50$ and this must be greater than $0$ if it is an increasing function.

I simplified this to $x^4 - 6x^2 + 10 > 0$. I know that I must prove this inequality true but I cannot work out how.

I am able to input various values of x and show them to be larger than 0 but am unsure how to do it algebraically.

I know for a quadratic, I can put it into a 'complete the square' form and then you can prove it to be larger than 0 as squaring something = positive and then adding a positive will remain positive. But am unsure how to do it where power of x > 2.

Comment: You're almost there, let $y=x^2$ then solve $y^2-6y+10>0$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Complete the square: $x^4-6x^2+10=(x^2-3)^2+1$

Answer (score 4):

Note that $x^4 - 6 x^2 + 10$ is a quadratic in $t = x^2$.  Complete the square for $t^2 - 6 t + 10$.

Comment: How can you just let $t = x^2$?

Comment: Why not?  You are free to give a name to any expression you want.

Comment: But are you then not solving for t rather than x?

Comment: Once you have $t^2 - 6 t + 10 = (t - 3)^2 + 1$, substitute back and you get $x^4 - 6 x^4 + 10 = (x^2 - 3)^2 + 1$.

Answer (score 0):

We can proof it also by definition.

Indeed, let $a>b$.

Thus, by AM-GM we obtain:
$$f(a)-f(b)=a^5-10a^3+50a-21-(b^5-10b^3+50b-21)=$$
$$=(a-b)(a^4+a^3b+a^2b^2+ab^3+b^4+50-10(a^2+ab+b^2))\geq$$
$$=(a-b)\left(2\sqrt{50(a^4+a^3b+a^2b^2+ab^3+b^4)}-10(a^2+ab+b^2)\right)=$$
$$=\frac{10(a-b)(2(a^4+a^3b+a^2b^2+ab^3+b^4)-(a^4+2a^3b+3a^2b^2+2ab^3+b^4))}{\sqrt{2(a^4+a^3b+a^2b^2+ab^3+b^4)}+a^2+ab+b^2}=$$
$$=\frac{10(a-b)(a^4-a^2b^2+b^4)}{\sqrt{2(a^4+a^3b+a^2b^2+ab^3+b^4)}+a^2+ab+b^2}>0$$ and we are done!

Answer (score -2):

Let rewrite that function as
$$f(x)=(x^5+50x)-(10x^3+21)$$
Obviously,
$$(10x^3+21)<(x^5+50x)$$
Hence, function is increasing :D

Comment: `Obviously ...` Not so, it doesn't hold for $\,x=0\,$, for example. `Hence, function is increasing` Even if it *did* hold, that would not imply monotonicity.

Comment: in question (first line) is noticed "and this must be greater than 0", so its correct :D

Comment: Other hand lets apply derivatives to show that $(10x^3+21)' < (x^5+50x)'$ => $30x^2 < 5x^4+50$ so the increse rate of f(x) takes postive value for each x>0.

Comment: `question (first line) is noticed ...` That's about the derivative, not the function itself. `Other hand lets apply derivatives` That would work. But your answer doesn't do that, so it doesn't actually address OP's question at all.

Comment: How no :D recall derivatives, we have $$f'(x)=5x^4-30x^2+50$$, substituiting x=0 we receive f'(0)=50>0 hence function is increasing :d why no :D

Comment: the same but other words)